# Windows .xap build from Phonegap Build

Tags: javascript, windows, cordova, phonegap-build

I have created an App in Phongap Build using html,css and js. Android works fine.The windows .xap file is build perfect but when i run it my Windows Lumia phone.just image is displayed .No functionality and js is working.

Comment: Hi 007DevilsWorkshop, it would help us if you showed us relevant code that you tried, and what output you expected. I also highly recommend reading through this page:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  It’s a fantastic resource to help you get the best solution to your question.

Comment: thanks **Newd**. Im new to this. i will improve soon :). I have created project in phonegap so that i can createapp for all the platform. I created zip of my project as given in "Getting Started with Build" i phonegap documentation. Added cofig file for that and uploded in Phonegap Build . As the output created 3 files .apk,.xap,.ipa . I tested .apk in android phone it worked fine. i dont have an Iphone to test. And when i run the .xap file in windows phone it just showed the logo imag i dont know what code is should upload so that you can understand . Please let me know. :)